# How to get a C4-symmetric (coincides after 90° rotation) matrix via `ImageData` from `Graphics`?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I tried an easy example with `Disk` centered at `{0,0}` with radius 1. Obviously, that object is C4-symmetric. Further, `ImageSize` is choosen such, that the length of list is odd (here: `{p+1}`. Than I would expect, (after `Binarize` and `ImageData`) that the center of `Disk` still coincides with the middle of `Dimensions` of the matrix. Unfortunately, it doesn't. Where is my error?

```
p = 20;
r = 1;

disk = Disk[{0, 0}, r];

object = Graphics[disk, ImageSize -> {p + 1}, PlotRange -> p/2];
data = ImageData[Binarize[object]];

Dimensions[data]
Position[data, 0] (*center of Disk should be {11,11}*)
data
```

[image]

Comment: Use this kind of artifact if you need such precision `Position[DiskMatrix[.1, 21], 1]`. Works like this `Position[ImageData[Image[DiskMatrix[.1, 21]]], 1.]`

Comment: Is the concept of `_Matrix` only working for Disks? What about a propeller-like shape (assume a C4-symmetric propeller)?

Comment: Graphics and Images aren't the proper vehicle for keeping exact calculations. Of course you can, but you'll have to take special safeguards so the data representation is kept untouched. If you need "pixel precision" you'll better work with matrices

Comment: `disk = Disk[{-10^-10, 10^-10}, r]` works.. so it's probably some rounding error?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I feared that answer... So, you suggest to define an analytical 2D-function and to `Table` that function afterwards, right? (just a short thought of mine, do you a have better solution?)

Comment: It depends heavily on your application .I don't have enough info about your project to answer that

Comment: @BlacKow: might be ist some kind of rounding error, but in your example the disk shape isn't preserved anymore... So maybe something else?

Comment: @Kay How isn't it preserved? I have five zeros now, I think it's better than having four (the little "cross" is more symmetric).

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: I learned, asking the right questions is extremly tricky. In Addition, the whole project is far bigger, than my actual problem. But I'll gie it a try of course. I need a matrix of 0`s and 1`s of a propeller-shaped C4-symmetric shape. One propeller arm (with some thickness) should consist of a quarter of a ring with a rounded cap.

Comment: @Kay also your code gives different result on my machine, I have  five zeros that are shifted, you have only four.

Comment: @BlacKow: I only have four zeros, doesn't matter which center is defined. Sounds like different boundary conditions...? Or version??

Comment: @Kay what version do you have? I posted my results as an "answer". Can you run my code and post results?

Comment: @BlacKow: done, watch your "answer"

Comment: @Kay what's you final goal? a Minecraft mod?

Comment: @BlacKow: I want to transfer that pixel array into an FDTD-based simulation tool [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-difference_time-domain_method) The method is working on a discritized space.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X and don't see the issue, but maybe you can try adding `BaseStyle -> {Antialiasing -> False}` to `Graphics`. See if that increases the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to literally enforce the symmetry:

```
p = 20;
r = 1;
disk = Disk[10.^-10 {1, 1}, r];
object = Graphics[disk, ImageSize -> {p + 1}, PlotRange -> p/2];
(data = ImageData[
    Binarize@
     ImageMultiply@
      NestList[ImageRotate, Image[object], 3]]) // ArrayPlot
Mean@Position[data, 0]
```

> {11,11}

Comment: How gross! +1 ...

Comment: Very impressive!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but here is what I get with Mathematica 10.0.1 on Mac

```
p = 20;
r = 1;
binData[d_] := 
  ImageData[Binarize[#]] &@
     Graphics[#, ImageSize -> {p + 1}, PlotRange -> p/2] &@d;
GraphicsRow[
 ArrayPlot /@ 
  binData /@ {Disk[{-10^-10, 10^-10}, r], Disk[{0, 0}, r]}]
```

[image]

On Version 10.0.1.0 Windows
Kay's result is different:
[image]

So it looks like rendering depends on OS. Which suggests that you shouldn't use `Graphics` objects when you want pixel precision.

Comment: Well, looks like you're right. Btw, what is the meaning of OS? "operating system"?

Comment: OS == Operating System

Comment: I get the lower asymmetric result with win/10.1.  Note if you look at the grayscale without doing `Binarize` you see a fairly minor asymmetry. Doing `Binarize[#,.8]` fixes this example, though I couldn't say how general that might be.

Comment: Another game to play here is to start with a larger image and resize: `ArrayPlot[
 ImageData[Binarize@ImageResize[#, 21]] &@Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 25],
   ImageSize -> {501}, PlotRange -> 250]]`

Comment: @george2079 I though about that, but it looks like OP really cares about symmetry, and I don't see a way how to enforce symmetry while using `Binarize`...  I don't think using `Graphics` is a good approach to his problem in general.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Dr. belisarius I tried to write an analytical 2d-function. In addition, I tabled just one quarter and joined the lists after consecutive 90° rotation in order to enforce C4-Symmetry. I was impressed, how easy it was, though I'm for sure not a coding expert! Here my code, even if it isn't the exact answer to my question, this is what I wanted:

```
periode = 550;
ArmRadius = 150;
WireRadius = 15;

rMin = ArmRadius - WireRadius;
rMax = ArmRadius + WireRadius;

Arm1[x_, y_] := (rMin <= Sqrt[x^2 + (y - ArmRadius)^2] <= rMax && 
    x >= 0 && 0 <= y <= ArmRadius);
Arm2[x_, y_] := (rMin <= Sqrt[(x + ArmRadius)^2 + y^2] <= rMax && 
    x >= 0 && 0 <= y <= ArmRadius);
Cap1[x_, y_] := (Sqrt[(x - ArmRadius)^2 + (y - ArmRadius)^2] <= 
    WireRadius);

func[x_, y_] := Arm1[x, y] || Arm2[x, y] || Cap1[x, y];
RegionPlot[func[x, y], {x, 0, periode/2}, {y, 0, periode/2}]
data = Table[
   If[func[x, y], 1, 0], {y, 0, periode/2, 1}, {x, 0, periode/2, 1}];
```

[image]
[image]

Testing the data delivered indeed C4-symmetry:

```
test1 = Transpose[Reverse[joi3]];
datatest = joi3 - test1;
Dimensions[datatest]
Count[Flatten[datatest], 0]
Count[Flatten[datatest], -1]
Count[Flatten[datatest], 1]
```

[image]

Thanks for your hints and efforts!!